# Adicionar uma pequena margem em uma div com text-align: right

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma div com material design bootstrap de tamanho 4 `col-md-4` que alinha para a direita meus textos usando `text-align: right`

O problema é que na mesma linha deste texto possui um icone, que também está alinhando para a direita porém com o `float: right`.

Meu texto e meu icone estão muito próximos, gostaria de adicionar uma margem no meu texto para a esquerda, para que ele se distanciasse um pouco do meu icone de "x".

Segue imagem:

Segue meu html e css responsável:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <span class="tituloAtributo">Tamanho</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <br>
     <span class="atributo">P</span>
   </div>

   <div class="col-12 col-md-4 alinhacentro">
      <span class="tituloAtributo">Cor</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <br>
      <span class="atributo">Cinza</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 alinhadireita">
        <span class="tituloAtributo">Cor</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <br>
        <span class="atributo">Rosa</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Meu css:

```
.alinhadireita{
    text-align: right;
}

.iconeexcluiatributo{
    color: #C62828;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    float: right;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso adicionar uma margem entre esse botão de x de forma que nao destrua minha responsividade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara é só dar um `margin-left` no ícone e não no texto

Veja como fica:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.13/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .alinhadireita {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .iconeexcluiatributo {
            color: #C62828;
            font-size: 14px !important;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <span class="tituloAtributo">Tamanho</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <span class="atributo">P</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 alinhacentro">
            <span class="tituloAtributo">Cor</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <span class="atributo">Cinza</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 alinhadireita">
            <span class="tituloAtributo">Cor</span> <i class="fa fa-close iconeexcluiatributo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <span class="atributo">Rosa</span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deu parcialmente certo. Mas na linha de baixo, no caso "rosa", tive que fazer o inverno, então foram criadas duas classes:

.ultimoelementocoluna{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.ultimoelementocolunacomclose{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

Comment: @RenaotPLS isso aconteceu pq vc quebrou a linha com um BR, mas o seu raciocínio foi correto, era apenas clocar a margin-left pro texto da segunda linha :D